# Android Calling a Class from Within onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Apologies for the noob question. I have an action bar button that injects a fragment into the main activity. The code works fine when it is inside the onOptionsItemSelected block, like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_chat:
            Log.v("Click", "Chat button");

            RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setId(999);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(ll.getId(), ChatFragment.newInstance()).commit();
            mainLayout.addView(ll);
            break;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

But I'm trying to have an external class handle the fragment insertion (since this is something that needs to be available to other activities as well). So I call it like this:

```
         case R.id.action_chat:
            ChatHandler chatHandler = new ChatHandler();
            chatHandler.goChat(View view);
            break;
```

And on the ChatHandler class:

```
public class ChatHandler {
        public void goChat(View view) {
            Log.v("GoChat", "Start");
            RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setId(999);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(ll.getId(), ChatFragment.newInstance()).commit();
            mainLayout.addView(ll);
        }
    }
```

My question is what parameters do I need to pass in the main activity goChat(View? view?) and how do I reference the main activity from the ChatHandler class, as in the this at LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't do UI task in non activity class. This way you will have to pass the whole activity instance and make few variables such as `mainLayout` public. Not a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to this

```
public void goChat(Context context)
{
    Log.v("GoChat", "Start");
    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)  ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
    ll.setId(999);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(ll.getId(), ChatFragment.newInstance()).commit();
    mainLayout.addView(ll);
}
```

Comment: won't be able to access `mainLayout`

Comment: Really try it yourself first. Also `getFragmentManager()` should be `context.getFragmentManager()`. `mainLayout` won't be accessible here. Also, doing UI operations like this is not a good (right) way

Comment: Worked for me after adding ((Activity)context). before getFragmentManager(). Thanks a lot.

@Rohit5k2 What do you mean this is not the right way? I'm a total noob and maybe I'm trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @AsinusRex Doing operation on your UI elements shouldn't be done a class which is not Activity or Fragment. I am not saying you can not but you should not.

Answer (score -1):

You should pass the activity as a parameter for the `goChat` method

```
case R.id.action_chat:
        ChatHandler chatHandler = new ChatHandler();
        chatHandler.goChat(this);
        break;
```

Then in that class:

```
public void goChat(Activity activity) {
        Log.v("GoChat", "Start");
        RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(activity);
        ll.setId(999);
        activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(ll.getId(), ChatFragment.newInstance()).commit();
        mainLayout.addView(ll);
    }
```

Comment: won't be able to access `mainLayout`